# Найти одинаковые файлы (картинки) команда find unix

Tags: shell

Значит скрипт качает на хост картинки с другого сервера, бывает сервер ему возвращает картинку заглушку (мол, изображения нет), видимо из-за большого кол-ва обращений. т.к. захожу на страницу картинка у товара есть.

Так вот, эти картинки ложатся в папку, но они сами понимаете бесполезны. хочется найти их и удалить. чтобы потом скрипт перекачивал их.

Так вот, вопрос, как можно find найти одинаковые файлы в папке и вывести их список или лучше сразу удалить. думаю искать надо как-то по хешу или размеру. т.к. картинки вроде одинаковы. как сделать чтобы find сравнивал хеш и и записывал имя картинки или сразу удалял. или лучше сделать это php скриптом?

Спасибо! Жду совету, желательно сразу строчку команды с параметрами! :)

Answer (score 2):

> $ ls
>
> file1  file2  file3  file4
>
> $sudo apt-get install fdupes
>
> ~/tmp$ fdupes .
>
> ./file2             
> ./file4
>
> ./file3